# Make an existing WordPress blog a subdirectory of a Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app on Heroku and a separate WordPress blog hosted on GoDaddy.  How can I route RailsApp.com/blog to the WordPress, while maintaining it as a subdirectory of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Rails3.1+ (+Rails4), you should follow these:
First, Add gem rack-proxy to Gemfile

*gem "rack-proxy"*

Then add file proxy.rb into Rails.root/lib like this:

```ruby
require 'rack/proxy'
class Proxy < Rack::Proxy
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def call(env)
    original_host = env["HTTP_HOST"]
    rewrite_env(env)
    if env["HTTP_HOST"] != original_host
      perform_request(env)
    else
      # just regular
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
  def rewrite_env(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if request.path =~ /^\/blog(\/.*)$/
      # enable these code if you set blog as ROOT directory in wordpress folder
      # env['REQUEST_PATH'] = '/'
      # env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH'] = '/'
      # env['PATH_INFO'] = '/' # set root path request
      env['REQUEST_URI'] = 'http://tinle1201.wordpressdomain.com' # your path
      env["SERVER_PORT"] = 80
      env["HTTP_HOST"] = "tinle1201.wordpressdomain.com" # point to your host
    end
    env
  end
end*
```

Register proxy to middleware into config/application.rb:

```ruby
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
module AdultSavings
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.middleware.use "Proxy"
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end*
```

Add this line into php file wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://tinle1201.wordpressdomain.com/blog');
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails configuration

Add to Gemfile:

```
gem "rack-reverse-proxy", :require => "rack/reverse_proxy"
```

Now we want /blog and /blog/ to be directed to the Wordpress instance from the Rails app.

Add this to your config.ru right before you run the app:

```
use Rack::ReverseProxy do
  reverse_proxy(/^\/blog(\/.*)$/,
    'http://CHANGEME.herokuapp.com$1',
    opts = {:preserve_host => true})
end
```

In config/routes.rb add a route:

```
match "/blog" => redirect("/blog/")
```

Comment: I'm very aware of that article, although it applies to heroku based wordpresses.  This is currently part of my attempted solution and I can get the blog to show up at the correct subdirectory, however when you click anything on the blog it switches to the blog's domain.

Comment: In an attempt to solve this I changed the Site Address URL on the wordpress to mywebsite.com/blog and added rewritebase /blog/ to .htaccess.  This works perfectly for an out-of-the-box wordpress because the posts are organized with extensions like /?p=1 where this goes to the first post.  The heavily modified blog I'm trying to work with has posts organized like blogurl.com/name-of-article and for some reason when I try the same exact solution clicking on the posts from the home page takes me to the root of my site instead of visiting the posts

Comment: Note that "rack-reverse-proxy" is not meant for production systems.  It is better to use your webserver (like Nginx or Apache) to configure proxy pass settings in production.