# Reverse proxy for blog with CloudFlare and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, cloudflare

I have a Rails website (example.com) and a Wordpress blog (blog.example.com), I also use CloudFlare. Is there a way to setup Wordpress blog to be at example.com/blog instead of blog.example.com? I saw [Make an existing WordPress blog a subdirectory of a Rails App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327761/make-an-existing-wordpress-blog-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app) and I can go down that route, but I would expect it to be possible to set this up in CloudFlare.

Comment: Did you ever solve this with CloudFlare?