# Issue proxy redirection from Wordpress to Heroku subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I want to redirect my Wordpress blog to an Heroku subfolder https://www.myapp.com/blog. I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327761/make-an-existing-wordpress-blog-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app) to do so but I get the following error:

> SocketError (Failed to open TCP connection to
>   https://www.blog.botletter.com/:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not
>   known)):

Here is my proxy file:

```
require 'rack/proxy'
class Proxy < Rack::Proxy
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def call(env)
    original_host = env["HTTP_HOST"]
    rewrite_env(env)
    if env["HTTP_HOST"] != original_host
      perform_request(env)
    else
      # just regular
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
  def rewrite_env(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if request.path =~ /^\/blog(\/.*)$/
      # enable these code if you set blog as ROOT directory in wordpress folder
      # env['REQUEST_PATH'] = '/'
      # env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH'] = '/'
      # env['PATH_INFO'] = '/' # set root path request
      env['REQUEST_URI'] = 'https://www.myapp.com/' # your path
      env["SERVER_PORT"] = 80
      env["HTTP_HOST"] = "https://www.blog.myapp.com/" # point to your host
    end
    env
  end
end
```

My application.rb config file contains the following:

```
...
class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.middleware.use "Proxy"
...
```

The route:

```
  get '/blog' => redirect("https://www.myapp.com/blog/")
```

And I added the following to the wp-config file of my Wordpress blog hosted with Bluehost:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.myapp.com/blog/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.myapp.com/blog/');
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `rack-proxy`. Add this to your routes:

`get '/blog/*article-slug', to: redirect("https://www.blog.botletter.com/%{article-slug}", status: 302)`

The 302 status is optional of course, but if you will always redirect it's probably better to. The redirect takes everything in the Heroku URL after `/blog/` and appends it to your new blog URL.

After this `http://your-heroku-app.com/blog/2017/this-is-a-test` will redirect to `https://www.blog.botletter.com/2017/this-is-a-test` for example.

Comment: Update, now it says there are too many redirections when I visit https://www.botletter.com/blog/

Comment: @AlphaNico is `botletter.com/blog` where your Heroku app? In that case you have to add the route I gave you after the one in which you declare `/blog` as the homepage of the app.

Comment: No, the app is at www.botletter.com and the blog is a wordpress hosted on Bluehost at blog.botletter.com. I want to put it at botletter.com/blog